# How to hash strings in python to match within 1 character?

Tags: python, string, search, hash

I've read about LSH hashing and am wondering what is the best implementation to match strings within 1 character?

```
test = {'dog':1, 'cat': 2, 'eagle': 3} 

test['dog']
>> 1
```

I would want to also return 1 if I lookup test['dogs'] or test['dogg'].  I realize that it would also return 1 if I were to look up "log" or "cog", but I can write a method to exclude those results.

Also how can I further this method for general strings to return a match within X characters?

```
string1 = "brown dogs"
string2 = "brown doggie"
```

Assuming only string1 is stored in my dictionary, a lookup for string2 would return string1.

Thanks

Comment: In short, you can't. Hash tables are the wrong tool for this.

Comment: That won't work, because what you're describing is not an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Comment: So are you trying to get the value for a key which is the most similar to a given key? Is that correct?

Comment: @SLaks I don't know what equivalence relation has to do with that.

Comment: @freakish: The key comparison (hash function) for a hash tables must be an equivalence relation.

Comment: @SLaks OK. But comparing by similarity *is* an equivalence relation ( depends on definition of *similarity* though ). I guess we need more info for that question.

Comment: I'm sure you could implement a LSH based mapping class in Python, it's a general purpose language. If you have problems getting it to work, come back with a concrete problem.

Comment: @freakish: No, it isn't.  `abc` == `abd`, and `abz` == `xbz`, but `abc` != `xbz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can define the similarity between 2 strings by the length of the start they share in common (3 for `doga` and `dogs`, for instance). This is simplistic, but that could fit your needs.

With this assumption, you can define this:

```
>>> test = {'dog':1, 'cat': 2, 'eagle': 3}
>>> def same_start(s1, s2):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(min(len(s1), len(s2))):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            break
        ret += 1
    return ret

>>> def closest_match(s):
    return max(((k, v, same_start(k, s)) for k, v in test.iteritems()), key=lambda x: x[2])[1]

>>> closest_match('dogs')  # matches dog
1
>>> closest_match('cogs')  # matches cat
2
>>> closest_match('eaogs') # matches eagle
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your relation is not 1:1, maybe you could define your own dict type with redefined `__getitem__` which could return a list of possible items. Here's what I mean:

```
class MyDict(dict):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    l = []
    for k, v in self.items():
      if key.startswith(k): # or some other comparation method
        l.append(v)
    return l
```

This is just an idea, probably other dict methods should be redefined too in order to avoid possible errors or infinite loops. Also, [@Emmanuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857578/296974) could be very useful here if you want only one item returned instead of the list, and that way you wouldn't have to redefine everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a Soundex function as your dictionary key?